# Is there a geometric interpretation for time dependent unitary transformations?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, gauge-theory, unitarity

Given a gauge transformation $|\psi\rangle \to |\psi'\rangle = U(t)|\psi\rangle$ where $U^\dagger (t) = U^{-1}(t)$, we know that the Hamiltonian in the new frame is given by $H' = UHU^\dagger + i\hbar \frac{\partial U}{\partial t}U^\dagger$. If for example we consider a Hamiltonian
$$
H = H_0 + \lambda(t) V
$$
and choose $U(\lambda(t))$ such that $UH_0U^\dagger$ is diagonal. In that case we write out the time derivative as
$$
i\hbar \frac{\partial U}{\partial t} U^\dagger = i\hbar \dot{\lambda}\frac{\partial U}{\partial \lambda}U^\dagger := \dot{\lambda} A'
$$
I've [seen](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.02229) $A = U^\dagger A' U$ be called the gauge potential (I don't really know anything about gauge theory other than the usual E&M, is there maybe a way to write a gauge covariant time derivative?). They also show that the gauge potential acts as the translation operator wrt. $\lambda$ in the energy eigenbasis, i.e.
$$
\langle m | A |n\rangle = \langle m | i\hbar \partial_\lambda |n\rangle
$$
So if I were to time evolve using the gauge potential as my Hamiltonian then the time evolution operator would be $U=e^{t\partial_\lambda}$ so it's a shift operator of $\lambda$ in the energy eigenbasis $U(t) |n(\lambda)\rangle = |n(\lambda +t)\rangle$. This made me wonder if there's a way to interpret the time evolution as some sort of combination of moving along $t$ and $\lambda$ and doing a gauge transformation into this new frame is then akin to untangeling the two directions and basically having orthogonal directions? I would imagine that in such a frame the time evolution would take a simpler form and that's one of the reasons why one might use say the Heisenberg picture.

I tried writing down the time evolution operator, but I can't work it out
$$
U_t = \mathcal{T}\exp\left[-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_0^t \mathrm{d}\tau U H U^\dagger + \int_0^t \mathrm{d}\tau \dot{\lambda} \frac{\partial U}{\partial \lambda}U^\dagger\right]
$$
but by assumption $UHU^\dagger$ is always diagonal so it can be written as $\sum_n E_n(\lambda) |e_n\rangle\langle e_n|$ where $|e_n\rangle$ doesn't depend on $\lambda$ or $t$ anymore. But in general I don't think these operators should commute so I don't know how to really simplify the timeordered exponential further (and I suspect you can't in such a general situation?).
$$
U_t = \mathcal{T}\exp\left[-\frac{i}{\hbar}\sum_n |e_n\rangle\langle e_n| \int_0^t \mathrm{d}\tau\ E_n(\lambda(\tau)) + \int_{\lambda_i}^{\lambda_f}\mathrm{d}\lambda\ \frac{\partial U}{\partial \lambda}U^\dagger \right]
$$

Comment: Why do you call it a gauge transformation?

Comment: Well that's what my professor called time dependent unitary transformations. Unfortunately I don't know very much about gauge theory. But the article I linked also refers to the 'gauge potential' and it leads to the Berry phase, connection and curvature which are all related to gauge theory?